# Add a NOT refundable surcharge on Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I had a surcharge extra fee on functions.php for woocommerce but i need that this surcharge are not refundable. THe idea is that make full refunds automatically but this surcharge are NOT REFUNDABLE and we need that the Order Status change automatically to REFUNDED on Woocommerce.

Anyone had do this before?

This the code used:

```
/**
 ** Surcharge for MercadoPago
 **/

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_mp_checkout_fee_for_gateway' );
  
function add_mp_checkout_fee_for_gateway() {
    $chosen_gateway = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' );
     if ( $chosen_gateway == 'woo-mercado-pago-basic' ) {
      WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Tasa de Emisión', 35 );
   }
}
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'refresh_checkout_on_payment_methods_change' );
   
function refresh_checkout_on_payment_methods_change(){
    wc_enqueue_js( "
       $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^=\'payment_method\']', function() {
           $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
   ");
}
```

Comment: _"The idea is that make full refunds automatically but this surcharge are NOT REFUNDABLE and we need that the Order Status change automatically to REFUNDED"_ - can you clarify this? what do you mean by "full refunds automatically"? also: change to an order status.. is that order status already provided? - Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [SO question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) & [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes. When we make a refund on Woocommerce to order status change automatically to Refunded, we need charge back all amount order (included products, taxes, shipping). Our need is do this when just product amount (no taxes or shipping) and the order changes to refunded.